# What is the connection between $l_p$ norms and "$l_p$ metrics"?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology, normed-spaces

In some textbooks metric spaces you sometimes encounter these  "$l_p$ metrics", $d_1, d_2, d_\infty$

(I don't think $l_p$ metric is very standard usage)

For example,

$d_1(x,y) := \sum\limits_i^m |x_i - y_i|$

$\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\| _1 := \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left| x_i \right| $

Is there a general $l_p$ metric and are $l_p$ metrics induced by $l_p$ norms?

Comment: In general, if you have a norm $\|\cdot\|$, you can define a metric that is induced by it by $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$. This is how we think about distances *between* points in Euclidean space. You take the vectors, subtract them and measure the length of that vector and that is the distance between them.

Comment: On the notation question, $l_p$ usually denotes a countably infinite-dimensional space, such as a set of infinite sequences.  I don't think I've seen it denote a finite-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$l_p$ metric on $\mathbb R^m$:
$$
d_p(x-y) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^m \big|x_i-y_i\big|^p\right)^{1/p}
$$
$1\le p < \infty$.  I will let you do the $l_\infty$ metric.

Comment: For the value of $p$, maybe it's more common to write $1\le p\le \infty$?

Comment: Yes.  Only that formula is not valid for $p=\infty$.  You have to use a different formula then.

Comment: Oh sorry I don't see this point.

Answer (score 1):

(some changes in order to improve precision)

About your last interrogation. Any normed vector space defines naturally a metric space by the relationship $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|_p$. Thus, indeed, any $\|\cdot\|_p$ norm induces naturally an $\ell_p$ "metrics" (synonym : "$\ell_p$ distance").

A point of vocabulary about the words "metrics" vs. "distance". "Metrics" is used in applications such as image processing. In mathematics, in differential geometry, it designates a tensor $g_{ij}$ ; topologists prefer "distance" to "metrics".